# Find html tag in window.selection() by javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using  `window.selection()` for coloring some text. Now I need to color a selection which do not contain a `<p>` tag.

Code:

```
 function abc() {
   var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
   span =  document.createElement('span');
   span.className = 'colored';
   span.appendChild(range.extractContents());
   range.insertNode(span);
 }
```

How can I check if `window.getSelection()` contains the `<p>` tag?

Comment: Wouldn't CSS ::selection work instead for your case? https://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `range.cloneContents()` to get a document fragment to work with and avoid mutating the DOM. Then run simple document queries like `querySelector()` on that document fragment to find any `p` tags:

```
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var docFragment = range.cloneContents();

if (docFragment.querySelector('p')) return;

var span = document.createElement('span');
span.className = 'colored';
range.surroundContents(span);
```

I also used `range.surroundContents()` to surround the range's contents in the `span` since that looks like all you're trying to do here.

Here's an example. Any selections that contain any part of the `p` tag don't have any effect, while all other selections get a yellow highlight:

```js
function abc() {
  var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  var docFragment = range.cloneContents();

  if (docFragment.querySelector('p')) return;

  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.className = 'colored';
  range.surroundContents(span);
 }
 
 window.onclick = abc
```

```css
.colored {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
stuff outside a p tag
<p>stuff inside a p tag</p>
more stuff outside a p tag
```

The caveat here is that any selections completely inside the `p` tag itself are still highlighted. If that's undesirable, you'd need to grab the selection's start or end container node and recursively check for a parent `p` tag. Example:

```js
function isInPTag(node) {
  return node && (node.tagName === 'P' || isInPTag(node.parentNode));
}

function abc() {
  var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  var docFragment = range.cloneContents();
  
  if (docFragment.querySelector('p') || isInPTag(range.startContainer)) return;

  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.className = 'colored';
  range.surroundContents(span);
}
 
 window.onclick = abc
```

```css
.colored {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
stuff outside a p tag
<p>stuff inside a p tag</p>
more stuff outside a p tag
```

Answer (score 2):

This will get you the selection's parent node's tag name:

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
if (selection && selection.anchorNode.parentNode.tagName === "P") {
    // code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a Jquery version to do that.

You can use .anchorNode attribute and get the parent of the selection then you can get the tag name of the parent easily by doing .prop("tagName").

```
$(range.anchorNode).parent().prop("tagName");
```